# Android Gallery and big images

Tags: android, memory

The `OutOfMemoryException` is a real pain in the ass on Android.
Currently I have a Gallery widget in which I set 30, 256x256px images, showing them by using BaseAdapter.

At some points, every second try let's say, the application crashes when I want to load the `ArrayList<Bitmap>` list as data to the Gallery.
I know it's stupid to keep 30 Bitmaps in memory, but what is the alternative. I have them in the resources and I need them to show in the Gallery.

**UPDATE (the Adapter):**

```
public class MyGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<MyDataObject> data = new ArrayList<MyDataObject>();

    public GalleryItemsAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public DataHolder getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);

        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.single_item_image_view);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(data.get(position).bitmap);

        return convertView;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<MyDataObject> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

    private class MyDataObject {
        public String title;
        public Bitmap image;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE (the error):**

```
I/dalvikvm( 9073): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a3c460 self=0x12828
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   | sysTid=9073 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074185352
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=437 stm=30 core=1
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2780)
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2717)
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:379)
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:174)
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm( 9073):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
```

Comment: post your adapter also..

Answer (score 0):

Create thumbnail for your images.

```
Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, origId, kind, options);
```

Comment: I dont work with MediaLibrary. I get the files from the resources.

Answer (score 0):

I´m gonna guess what´s the problem here:

In the onCreateView method of your adapter you create a new view in any case.

What you want to do is to check if the view given by parameter is already created:

```
@override
public abstract View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
if(view==null)
   // inflate the view 
else{
   // use view how it is
 }

.......
return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read this article on the android development site on how to deal with bitmaps and the memory error

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html